# Replacing a text file with a directory name using sed command

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have the directories structure as below:

```
Folder1/
  |____file.txt
Folder2/
  |____file.txt 
Folder3/
  |____file.txt
  :
Foldern/
  |____file.txt
```

Each .txt file in the directories has a word that I want to replace with the directory name.

file.txt:

```
"name": "Engineering",
```

I am looking to replace the word Engineering with the directory name, e.g. for Folder1:

```
"name": "Folder1"
```

My intial attempt is as below:

```
for f in Folder*; do (cd $f; echo $f; sed -i -e "s/Engineering/Folder*/" file.txt); done
```

However, the sed command doesn't seem to see `Folder*` as Folder numbers.

Comment: Great, catch, Freddy! It worked now:)

Comment: Those files don't happen to be JSON files? If so, using `jq` rather than `sed` may be preferable (if one know anything about the structure of those JSON files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to `cd` into the directory. You can loop over the file paths and extract the folder name:

```
for file in Folder*/file.txt; do
  sed -i -e "s/Engineering/${file%%/*}/" "$file"
done
```

The parameter expansion `${file%%/*}` removes the longest suffix `/*` and leaves the folder name.

Comment: Freddy, many thanks for the support!

Comment: Hi Freddy, I noticed that the ${file%%/*} sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't!

Comment: Sometimes, I get empty folder name!

Comment: What is the pattern for the file path when the folder name is empty?

Comment: I would say e.g. jk-z30-t50-k001-za*/file.txt intead of Folder*/file.txt!

Comment: Hm, that looks okay. I thought you might have a folder with a subfolder like `Folder/subdir*/file.txt` where you would need the shortest pattern `${file%/*}` to get `Folder/subdirx` instead of `Folder` as result. Have you checked the output of `echo "file=$file, folder=${file%%/*}"` in the loop?

Comment: And if your folder name contains slashes, make sure your `sed` command contains a different separator like `"s|...|...|"` (choose one that doesn't occur in the folder name).

Comment: Hi Freddy, thanks again for the help. So, my folder structure is; /c/david/Results_for_me_Final/TA-3-03/Folder_SETUP*/file.txt

Comment: Use a different separator in `sed` and one `%` in the parameter expansion. 
Two `%%` remove the longest pattern of `/*` which is the complete folder path: `sed -i -e "s|Engineering|${file%/*}|" "$file"`

Comment: Hey Freddy, this change sed -i -e "s|Engineering|${file%/*}|" "$file" led to put the entire path instead of the folder name!

Comment: Is that not what you wanted? If you only want the _last_ folder, you need to remove the filename first and then remove all previous path elements: `path=${file%/*}; sed -i -e "s|Engineering|${path##*/}|" "$file"`